# Получить список id sum(count) sql

Tags: mysql

Подскажите пожалуйста, как я могу выполнить такой запрос, мне нужно сделать выборку id где суммируется количество товаров заказа:

```
select count(*) 
FROM orders 
WHERE id IN (SELECT id_order 
             from order_products 
             WHERE sum(count)>='3' 
              AND sum(count)<='5')
```

Понимаю что запрос не правильный, но как можно решить проблему?

Comment: Опишите словами что вы хотите получит

Comment: *Понимаю что запрос не правильный* Хотя бы опишите, какую логику вы пытались реализовать получая этот текст запроса. А мы расскажем, где она расползлась с кодом. Логику расписывайте по элементарным, в одно действие, шагам, и сразу - как Вы написали реализующий этот шаг код.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Второй запрос вероятно должен выглядеть так (подразумевается что поле count содержит число)

```
SELECT id_order from order_products 
GROUP BY id_order
HAVING sum(count)>=3 AND sum(count)<=5)
```